# strtok not working as expected, works only for first few iterations

Tags: c, strtok, string.h

I'm using strtok to split up a string, it works as expected for the first 4 iterations, but starts messing up after that. The program is supposed to take a line such as "david 1 2 3 4 5" and print out the name plus the sum of the numbers "david 15"... However I am having a problem with strtok.

EDIT: I make number a pointer for later uses of the code (this is only a snippet)

This is my C script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char str1[50];
char *token;
char *end;
long int *number;
int loop = 1;
while(loop){
    fgets(str1,50,stdin);
    token = strtok(str1," ");
    printf("%s ",token);
    *number = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        if(token != NULL){
            *number = *number + strtol(token,&end,0);
        }
    }
    printf("%li\n",*number);
}
```

With this input:

```
David 10 10 10 10 10
```

I get this output:

```
David 40
```

The expected output is:

```
David 50
```

Suspecting strtok, I put these test print statements:

```
char str1[50];
char *token;
char *end;
long int *number;
int loop = 1;
while(loop){
    fgets(str1,50,stdin);
    token = strtok(str1," ");
    printf("%s\n",token);
    *number = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        printf("before new token: %s\n",token);    // <---HERE
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        printf("after new token: %s\n\n",token);   // <---HERE
        if(token != NULL){
            *number = *number + strtol(token,&end,0);
        }
    }
    printf("%li\n",*number);
}
```

And with the same input of:

```
David 10 20 30 40 50
```

I get:

```
David
before new token: David
after new token: 10

before new token: 10
after new token: 20

before new token: 20
after new token: 30

before new token: 30
after new token: 4<

before new token: 4@
after new token: (null)

64
```

As you an see it works fine during the first few iterations, but after that things start going bad. If anyone has any idea what is happening, I would greatly appreciate the advice :) thanks!

Comment: Just for fun, what happens if you add a space after the `40`?

Comment: there already is a space after 40. the input is David 10 20 30 40 50

Comment: `number` doesn't point to anything defined...

Comment: In your particular case, the uninitialized `number` pointer happens to point to `str[16]`, the `0` character in value `40`. This means that you modify your input string when summing the values. After adding 10, 20, and 30, `str[16]` is set to 60 (little endian) which is the ASCII code for `<`. That's why you get the `4<` token. This is parsed as 4, added to 60, so in the next iteration, the old token contains `@` (ASCII 64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get 40 instead of 50 is that you drop the first token (i.e. the one that you get from `strtok` when you pass `str1`, not `NULL`). You need to add it to the sum before entering the loop, or re-organize the loop to add first and call `strtok` next:

```
number = 0; // There is no point in making "number" a pointer
token = strtok(str1," ");
while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s ",token);
    number += strtol(token,&end,0);
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YgRHke)

Comment: I'm programming in C by the way. hmm doesn't work, I put the print before the strtok line in the while loop, does the same thing

Comment: @Vaderico Works perfectly for me. Please see the demo link that I added at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Ahh okay just checked it out and it works perfectly. Thank you so much! upvoted

Answer (score 5):

The variable `number` is a pointer (why?) but you never make it point anywhere, therefore when you dereference it you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution? *Don't* make it a pointer!

Comment: please refer to my edit. I need it to be a pointer for later uses, this is just a snippet.

Comment: @Vaderico You still need to make it point somewhere. Also, you most likely don't need it as a pointer, since you can use e.g. `&number` to make a pointer out of a non-pointer variable.